# can a 32 bit only DLL in web application cause performance decrease?

Tags: .net, asp.net

Our product, a Web forms .NET application, is starting to meet 64 bits Windows servers and we have a 32bit DLL from one of our component vendors (its a hardware key, actually).

I checked the instructions here "[compiling a .net application with either a 32-bit or 64-bit dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507227/compiling-a-net-application-with-either-a-32-bit-or-64-bit-dll)". It is also what our vendor sugested.

My question: is there a performance impact on compiling a web application to run on x86 mode ?

Please don't flame me for using a hardware key. I know it's evil but I can't help it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually found out there is no target platform for asp.net applications. The "target platform" is set on the IIS application pool. You can use the 32 bit dll if you set the application pool to 32 bit. In the end I had the supplier provide a 64 bit dll and it should solve the problem.